# Determining the latency of audio processing in iPhone devices

Tags: ios, audio, playback

I want to create an app that records audio, processes it and plays it right away (all of the 3 happen instantly) and I couldn't find the hardware specification of any iOS device regarding the issue. Is the thing possible? If it is, where do you suggest to start? And most important, where can I find those specs?

Answer (score 1):

Check out remoteIO. Michael Tyson wrote a well known series of posts on this available here . .

http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

I can get the round trip latency (measured using a [MLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_length_sequence) sample) down to 12ms on an iPhone 4S with fairly substantial DSP processing in the signal path. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  The only low-level public iOS audio APIs are buffer callback based, with the smallest buffers being a few milliseconds in length, and thus will always incur a non-zero latency.